# Switching env files when deploying on ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm actually deploying my Laravel App on ElasticBeanstalk.

I want to switch the .env file based on the environment but I can't managed to make my test work correctly.

Here is what I have written in my .ebextensions/02-env-file.config

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    ENV_NAME: '`{ "Ref" : "AWSEBEnvironmentName" }`'  # assign the actual env name to ENV_NAME

container_commands:
  01-config-environment:
    command: mv /var/app/ondeck/.env.staging /var/app/ondeck/.env
    test: '[[ $ENV_NAME = "Staging" ]]'
    command: mv /var/app/ondeck/.env.demo /var/app/ondeck/.env
    test: '[[ $ENV_NAME = "Demo" ]]'
```

But it seems that it always run the last command whatever my environment is.
I guess i'mm missing something here but can't find what.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally have the answer to my question. I post it here in case someone has the same problem.

It turns out that if we bundle 2 commands, ElasticBeanstalk may not execute them correctly.

To achieve what I want I need to split my commands in 2 like this :

```
container_commands:
  01-config-environment-staging:
    command: mv .env.staging .env
    test: '[[ ${ENV_NAME} = "Staging" ]]'
  02-config-environment-demo:
    command: mv .env.demo .env
    test: '[[ ${ENV_NAME} = "Demo" ]]'
```